# Storyboards and UITabBarControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm using Storyboards for the first time. It's mostly going okay, but one situation is very unclear:

I'm using a Tab Bar Controller as my Initial View Controller. I have three tabs, and they're each an instance of the same view controller class, the only difference being that I want to pass in a different array to each instance, to display different data.

My thought was I could use `prepareForSegue:` in the `UITabBarController` instance to pass the proper array to each destination view controller…but maybe `UITabBarController` isn't using segues to display each view controller in a tab, because there's no way in IB to specify a Storyboard ID for the "segue" to the tab contents. (If I select the segue that connects the Tab Controller to the child Controller, IB just says "Not Applicable" in the customizer area.)

So my question is: how can I handle this situation in IB?

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController uses segues, but it is a special kind of segues. Select a UITabBarController in the IB, and open the Connections inspector in the Utilities area. You'll see that there are Presenting Segues in the bottom (those are handled by prepareForSegue) and Triggered Segues, which include `viewControllers` segues. Those are the segues to tabs inside a tab bar. They are not really segues, they are more like references.

In order to use one class for three different view controllers as tabs in IB, you should add three empty (or not) view controllers as tabs and specify their class using the Identity Inspector in the Utilities area. The class can be the same for all three.

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the Storyboard ID for one of these segues, so I can identify which one is which in code?

Comment: @GregMaletic, I'm afraid, it's not possible using `prepareForSegue`. One possible solution would be to implement a custom `UITabBarController` subclass, make it a delegate of the tab bar and handle `-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` (actually, you'd need a custom subclass to implement `prepareForSegue` anyway).

Comment: @GregMaletic, sorry, it's not `UITabBarDelegate`, it's `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. And probably it might be a better idea to use `shouldSelectViewController` instead (customize it and return true). But `didSelect` might also be OK.